# Difference between router and gateway

Tags: router, network, gateway

What is the exact difference between router and gateway? In Network configuration we set the default gateway IP address, but in reality we call the device configured with that IP address as router?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Router* describes the general technical function (layer-3 forwarding) or a hardware device intended for that purpose, while *gateway* describes the function for the local segment (providing connectivity to elsewhere). You could also state that "you set up a router as gateway". Another term is *hop* which describes the forwarding in between subnets.

It's just a matter of perspective, the device is the same.

Answer (score 18):

> What is the exact difference between router and gateway?

A router is a device/service that provides the function of routing IP packets between networks.

A gateway (in network terms) is a router that provides access for IP packets into and/or out of the local network.

> In Network configuration we set the gateway ip address, but in reality we call the device configured with that ip address as router?

Specifically, the gateway you are likely referring to is the *default gateway* which is the router to which a client (or source device) sends IP packets that are destined somewhere other than the local network and for which the client has no "better" route.

A gateway always has to be a router, but a router does not have to be a gateway.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the statement "A gateway always has to be a router, but a router does not have to be a gateway" in detail ?

Comment: Because a gateway's purpose is to route packets into/out of a local network segment for other devices, it will always be a router. However a router can be attached to a local network without performing any sort of routing into/out of the local network segment for other devices. It could be using the connection to a local network segment for a number of different purposes (for example, including but not limited to, management purposes such as monitoring, reporting, logging, etc.).

Comment: @YLearn So, gateway if ever configured will have same ip as that of router ?

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin, assumption on my part is that by "gateway" you are referring to the default gateway configured on a device. Then specifically, the gateway would be configured as the IP of the router functioning as the gateway for that network or client.

Answer (score 6):

A router is a layer 3 device i.e It cannot modify the IP address of the packet, it can only change the MAC Address it can route the packet, whereas a gateway could be NAT capable, or can act as a firewall in case of a NAT-capable gateway it can change the packet's IP address and more capable gateways can block traffic

- Layer2 Devices - Switches
- Layer3 Devices - Routers
- Layer2- Layer7    Devices - Gateways/Firewalls/IDC (usually implement
  DPI -deep packet    inspection)

> Gateways are distinct from routers or switches in that they communicate using more than one protocol and can operate at any layer of the 7 layer OSI model of networking. - *Wikipedia*

Comment: Not sure this is strictly true when it comes to acceleration devices and transparent caching etc

Comment: If it is a router it is true, if we add special features and call it a router it is not true.Any router that operates above layer 3 is not a L3 Router

Comment: by that definition I don’t think there are any routers left from any of the big manufacturers, sure they do routing but they also do a heck of a lot more

Comment: Yes, even so called switches (commercial) do routing and NAT. Definitions are only theroretical